# Angular ngRx filter

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I started learning ngRx and I have basic problem.
In my class I have:

```
  @select() todos;
```

then when I press button I want to filter that data and return to html filtered data. Tried something like

```
public onSubmit(): void {
const example = this.todos.filter(todo => todo.lang === 'pl');

console.log(example);
```

}

But I get error:

> ERROR TypeError: this.todos.filter is not a function

Anyone some ideas?

Comment: Could you give a [mcve] and expand on *"errors"*?

Comment: edited question

Comment: What is `@select()`? It's not from base ngrx.

Comment: import { NgRedux, select } from '@angular-redux/store';
Its anonymous subject to the todos from store.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do not know the `@select()` decorator but I guess it returns an `Observable`.

If (as you should), you're not patching rxjs prototype to add every methods you need (map, filter, etc) it's normal that doing `this.todos.filter`.

Instead you should use the `pipe` operator like that:

```
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

... 

this.todos.pipe(
  filter(... your conditions ...)
)
```

Also, doing the following will not do what you expect (for 2 reasons):

```
const example = this.todos.filter(todo => todo.lang === 'pl');

console.log(example);
```

**First reason:**
You have to differentiate `filter` from `rxjs` and `filter` on an `array`.

Here, on every new value sent by the observable, you want to **modify** the value --> **filter** it.

To modify an `Observable`, you have to use the **map** operator. So it'd be:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@select() todos$; // $ is just to remember it's an Observable + avoid shadowing variable name

...

const example$ = this.todos$.pipe(
  map(todos => todos.filter(todo => todo.lang === 'pl'))
);
```

**Second reason:**
An Observable, just like a `promise`, is **async**.
Which means that you cannot do:

```
const example = this.todos.filter(todo => todo.lang === 'pl');

console.log(example);
```

and expect the result of the filter to be displayed. You'll just try to display an Observable (an object).

Displaying a result with `console.log` for example is called a side effect. And when you want to do some side effects within an Observable, there's the `tap` function (previous called `do` before pipe operator).

So the final solution here would be:

```
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@select() todos$;

...

const example$ = this.todos$.pipe(
  map(todos => todos.filter(todo => todo.lang === 'pl')),
  tap(todos => console.log(todos))
);
```

**EDIT 1:**
If @select is getting the exact same part of your store based on variable name you may not be able to name it with a $ suffix, but you got my point.

**EDIT 2:**
Before trying to use ngrx or ngredux, I suggest you to learn rxjs and redux separately, and by example with small projects. In my opinion, you should try to get the basis of both before trying to mix those 2 (powerful but no easy at first) concepts.